# How to make an image provider from an Icon in flutter for FadeInImage widget?

Tags: flutter

I want to use `FadeInImage` with an icon as a placeholder.

`FadeInImage` has few constructors.

In a default constructor it takes `ImageProvider` as a placeholder, and in `FadeInImage.MemoryNetwork(` it takes `Uint8List` as a memory placeholder.

The third constructor creates AssetImage, but I doubt that is useful here.

Is there any way to convert an Icon to one of those data types?

Example signature:

`FadeInImage(placeholder: iconPlaceholder, image: NetworkImage("url"))`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Icons are really just text from a font, so its tricky to make that into an image. The trick in the [cookbook](https://flutter.io/cookbook/images/fading-in-images/) should work. Use a Stack with the Icon behind and a transparent placeholder.

```dart
body: Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Center(child: Icon(Icons.something)),
    Center(
      child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
        placeholder: kTransparentImage,
        image:
            'https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/master/_includes/code/layout/lakes/images/lake.jpg?raw=true',
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

For `kTransparentImage`, see [this](https://pub.dev/packages/transparent_image).

Comment: here what is "kTransparentImage"?

Comment: how can I use output of "FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(" as imageProvider? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a package that can take Widget as a placeholder

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image

```
  ClipOval(
    child: CachedNetworkImage(
  placeholder: new Container(
    height: height,
    width: height,
    child: Icon(Icons.accessibility),
    color: kGrey400,
  ),
  imageUrl: photoUrl,
  height: height,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
));
```