# How to fadein a decorationImage in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to fade in a decoration image and can't figure out how.

The image property needs an ImageProvider, while FadeInImage widget is a StatefulWidget.

This is what I've tried to work with:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration (
  image: DecorationImage(
    fix: BoxFit.cover,
    image: ...
  ),
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an image provider from an Icon in flutter for FadeInImage widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717052/how-to-make-an-image-provider-from-an-icon-in-flutter-for-fadeinimage-widget)

Comment: I dont think so, I used as a DecorationImage, There need a ImageProvider type Widget.

Comment: Hi, did you check this class provided by flutter?https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html

Comment: @mengqiaohu I've fixed up your question a bit. Rather than pasting in a link to an image with code, it's better just to paste the code in =).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're not going to be able to animate a DecorationImage. As you've stated, DecorationImage only provides an ImageProvider, which doesn't really allow for animation (at least as far as I know).

You might be able to write a new AnimatedDecorationImage by taking part of the code from DecorationImage and editing it, but that would be pretty complicated.

What I'd recommend is instead to use a stack to simulate the same thing as DecorationImage. This would allow you to use the FadeInImage widget.

That would look something like this:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    FadeInImage(
      placeholder: MemoryImage(....),
      image: NetworkImage(...),
    ),
    <your widget, I assume a container?>
  ],
)
```