# How can I show an asset Image while NetworkImage is loading

Tags: flutter, networkimageview

I am not able to show a circular loading indicator or an image while flutter is loading the image from the network.

```
image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                        Juegos_de_siempre[index].url_foto,
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter's documentation [suggested](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/images/network-image#placeholders-and-caching) the usage of `FadeInImage` for the placeholder functionality. Here's a [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/images/fading-in-images) to an example on Flutter's documentation.

You cannot use `FadeInImage` inside a `DecorationImage`, so you have to wrap it inside a `Stack` instead like shown in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52120265).

Answer (score -1):

Use `CacheNetworkImage` Package.Click [here](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image).

This is sample code.

```
CachedNetworkImage(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  imageUrl: imageUrl,
                  placeholder: (context, url) => const Center(
                    child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
                  ), // replace with your asset image
                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                      const Icon(Icons.error),
                ),
```