# Switch widget - use an icon for the activeThumbImage property (it is of type ImageProvider)

Tags: flutter

I would like to use an icon for the activeThumbImage property of the Switch widget.  Something like the following:

```
Switch(
  value: isSelected,
  activeThumbImage: FontAwesomeIcons.heart,
),
```

An Icon is a Widget and the property requires an Image Provider so this will not work.  Is there any way to convert an Icon to an ImageProvider to make this work?

Comment: This seems to be tricky since the icon is just a glyph in a font. I found related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717052/how-to-make-an-image-provider-from-an-icon-in-flutter-for-fadeinimage-widget but It could be possible to draw text on canvas and then convert it into image, but it probably be simpler to just use .jpg/.png made from that icon .svg

Comment: thank you, I think the related question isn't suitable.  Yes, I think jpg is going to be the easiest option; I think I'm gonna do that.