# How to use icon as image

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to use Icon as image? I'm trying to display background image in CircleAvatar. If no image provided use icon as background image

```
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: _image != null
                ? AssetImage(_image.path)
                : Icon(Icons.email), //<- here use icon as image
          )
```

I know I can do something like this

```
          CircleAvatar(
            child: _image == null ? Icon(Icons.email) : null,
            backgroundImage:
                _image != null ? AssetImage(_image.path) : null,
          )
```

I just found it a bit tedious adding 2 parameters for same purpose and also I want to use child parameter for something else

Comment: What else do you want to use the child parameter for? In most cases you can use [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50724141/617159

Comment: @LambdaFairy sure I can use `Stack`. I know Stack very well. As I mention in my question I found it a bit tedious to do it this way.. If there is a way to use icon as image then we wouldn't need to use stack and just add the icon into `backgroundImage` if statement and use `child` for other things like text and so on

Comment: @LambdaFairy well according to that answer from your link, it looks like I will have to turn the icon manually into the image.. In other words there is no way to use icon as image